# Finding and replacing specific text between two strings?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, command-line, sed

I have about a thousand XML files in one folder. Each XML file has about 100 items in it. Each item is on a separate line.

I need to search and replace text that's only between

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
```

and

```
]]></content:encoded>
```

I only need to replace the following:

- `'` is replaced with `&apos;`
- `"` is replaced with `&quot;`
- `<` is replaced with `&lt;`
- `>` is replaced with `&gt;`

I use `sed` for mass finding/replacing all the time, but can't get it to work when I just want to find/replace between strings like this

I'm up for using whatever you guys think is best

Comment: Is it valid xml or are you trying to make it valid?

Comment: Well the invalid part is the fact that there are unescaped characters like `"` in it, that's why I'm trying to replace them.

Comment: That seems like a really weird thing to do.  Normally if you want to include the character `<` as part of text in XML you would *either* use the escaped form: `&lt;` or put it inside a CDATA section.  Your question implies you want to do *both* - which will result in double-escaped data. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Can we assume that "start" and "end" tokens (as you've specified above) are not nested?

Comment: I hope you've heard that  regular expressions are not the way top go to process XML data. The best excuse I have heard is that the data isn't *valid* XML so a proper parser won't accept it, but *any* character is valid within a *CDATA* section so you shouldn't have a problem. What's more, if you make those changes then the replacement strings will be taken literally, and any software that works properly will not recognise any character entities. What is your purpose? Are you trying to get your data through a non-standard-compliant software layer? A sample of your data would help enormously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the "start token" is found, the solution needs to collect (match) everything except the "end token" - but scanning for the negation of a string is surprisingly difficult. (see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=606495) and [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=588315) for some discussion).

Below is a solution subject to a couple of reasonable (I believe) constraints

1. The tokens can't be nested i.e. `[start] stuff [start] stuff [end] stuff [end]`; and
2. Neither the start or end tokens can be split across lines ie

   `hello world <content:enco`

   `ded><![CDATA[ [stuff] ... etc`

My solution is long but liberally commented and being more straight forward rather than clever is (arguably) easier to maintain;

```
use v5.12;

my $start_string =  '<content:encoded><![CDATA[' ;
my $end_string   =  ']]></content:encoded>' ;
my $start_token  =  quotemeta $start_string ;
my $end_token    =  quotemeta $end_string ;

sub do_subs {
    my $text = shift ;
    $text =~ s/'/\&apos;/g ;
    $text =~ s/"/\&quot;/g ;
    $text =~ s/\</\&lt;/g ;
    $text =~ s/\>/\&gt;/g ;
    return $text ;
}

my $subs_mode = 0;                # "substitution mode" off/on
while (<>) {
    my $line_remnants = $_ ;      # what's left - intially, the whole line
    my $replacement = "" ;        # replacement for whole line

    # while there's something left of the line to process
    while ( ! $line_remnants eq "" )  {
        if ($subs_mode) {
            # Currently substituting.  Scan for end_token
            if ($line_remnants =~ /^ (.*?) $end_token (.* \n) /x)  {
                # Found end_token -> &do_subs on "preface" & add end_string
                $replacement .= do_subs($1) . $end_string ;
                $line_remnants = $2 ;
                $subs_mode = 0 ;
            }
            else {
                # Didn't find end_token -> &do_subs on all of what's left
                $replacement .= do_subs($line_remnants) ;
                $line_remnants = "" ;
            }
        }
        else {
            # Currently NOT substituting.  Scan for start_token
            if ($line_remnants =~ /^ (.*?) $start_token (.* \n) /x)  {
                # Found start_token -> append "preface" and start_string
                $replacement .= $1 . $start_string ;
                $line_remnants = $2 ;
                $subs_mode = 1 ;
            }
            else {
                # Didn't find start_token -> append all of what remains
                $replacement .= $line_remnants ;
                $line_remnants = "" ;
            }
        }
    } # while ! $line_remnants ...

    # Nothing left of line, print replacement
    print $replacement
}
```

It's 'unix filter' style - reads on STDIN, transforms and writes on STDOUT.  When fed this;

```
hello world
<content:encoded><![CDATA[ ' " ]]></content:encoded>
Here it comes: <content:encoded><![CDATA[ No quotes
like these in here ' " or relation ops like these < > ",>'
More non-allowed " ' <>'" - then the end: ]]></content:encoded>
these qotes should come through ' "<>
Start and End on one line - no data
<content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
Start and End repeatedly on one line - single char
'<content:encoded><![CDATA[']]></content:encoded>'<content:encoded><![CDATA[']]></content:encoded>
```

... it produces;

```
hello world
<content:encoded><![CDATA[ &apos; &quot; ]]></content:encoded>
Here it comes: <content:encoded><![CDATA[ No quotes
like these in here &apos; &quot; or relation ops like these &lt; &gt; &quot;,&gt;&apos;
More non-allowed &quot; &apos; &lt;&gt;&apos;&quot; - then the end: ]]></content:encoded>
these qotes should come through ' "<>
Start and End on one line - no data
<content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
Start and End repeatedly on one line - single char
'<content:encoded><![CDATA[&apos;]]></content:encoded>'<content:encoded><![CDATA[&apos;]]></content:encoded>
```

I hope it's of some use.